# Error in fetch(key): lazy-load database in base R

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

My RStudio server interface is occasionally returning an error dialog:

[image: Error Retrieving Help]

and printing the following to my R console:

```
Error in fetch(key) : 
  lazy-load database '$INSTALLED_PATH/lib64/R/library/base/help/base.rdb' is corrupt
```

It also seems to break fonts in plots:

[image: Missing fonts]

Searching through similar error messages on StackOverflow pointed towards the problems being specific to custom packages. However, this is a problem in base. It persists across R sessions. Any suggestion on how I might make this error go away?

Comment: I would assume that the console message is correct:  something has corrupted your R installation, or is corrupting reads from it.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Reinstalling R produced the same error. Fortunately, a new version came out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an Rstudio problem with the current session, but there is an easy fix for it.

Simply restart your Rstudio!

Solution found [here](https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/298#issuecomment-368258575).